# CUPS ignoring lp -o options when printing to Ricoh 4000 with Fiery E-5100

Tags: ubuntu, printing, cups

I'm having difficulties controlling which paper type, size and tray when printing from the command line using either lp or lpr.   The commands appear to just ignore the -o options altogether and print as if the paper is plain letter in the default tray.  My intentions are Letter size, Thick 2, and Bypass Tray.

I've tried configuring the printer as socket:// & ipp:// with several ppd files.   Ricoh doesn't seem to have a ppd file just for Ubuntu so I have tried the PPD files in the windows and mac downloads.   The default cups drivers didn't even understand that the printer could do color nor identify the proper trays.

Here is the latest command I'm using to print:

```
lp -d printer9-o media=Letter,Thick2,ManualFeed   /tmp/order.pdf
```

The lpoptions list and ppd files are really long but I can paste it in if it's helpful.

Linux version 3.16.0-30-generic (buildd@kissel) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 15 17:43:14 UTC 2015

CUPS vs 1.7.2.

I can set the defaults in CUPS to print to the Bypass tray, with Thick 2 paper and letter size but this isn't ideal.  Everything then goes through the bypass tray instead of the auto selected tray.  We have special forms int the bypass tray so this is not a good option.

I've read a little about alternate instances of the same printer but I'd prefer to handle this through the program via command line options.

Where do I go from here?